# Why my tkinter app shows Tk or Toplevel when i stop with mouse over the icon?

Tags: python, tkinter, window-managers

I'm experimenting with python and tkinter.
I have a main tk window (tk.Tk) and a splash window (tk.Toplevel)

I added an icon to both windows using the following line

```
self.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file=globali.IMG_PATH + 'virtuve_ico.png'))
```

It's working fine but if I go with my mouse over the icon on icon tray (taskbar) it shows a text saying 'Tk' or 'Toplevel. I would like to change it to "My App Name".

[Toplevel on mouse over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01HHx.png)
[Tk on mouse over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoVRs.png)

Is that possible?

Thanks to everybody

Comment: Maybe `self.title("My App Name")`?

Comment: That's for the title bar, I already set that

Comment: In windows, there is no the problem after I set the title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [[rhel-w-tkinter-python3-changing-the-activity-name-from-tk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59144939)

Comment: I'm using linux, I did't try on other platforms

Comment: @stovfl that is working if I use root = tk.Tk(className="My App") but I'm using my own tkinter subclass and it's not working there

Comment: ***using my own tkinter subclass***: So you didn't pass this argument to the base class? [Edit] your question according the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: Ok. found the solution for my case. I will post the answer in a minute. Thanks @stovfl

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution in my case was to add a className parameter like this

```
 root = tk.Tk(className="My App")
```

But because I am using my own class I had also to pass the className to the superclass

```
root = MyClass(className="My App")
root.mainloop()

class MyClass(tk.Tk):
def __init__(self, className):
    super().__init__(className=className)
```

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

If setting the title doesn't work, try using the `wm_iconname()` method of the `tkinter.Tk` object.

```
In [1]: import tkinter as tk

In [2]: root = tk.Tk()
Out[2]: <tkinter.Tk object .>

In [3]: root.wm_iconname?
Signature: root.wm_iconname(newName=None)
Docstring:
Set the name of the icon for this widget. Return the name if
None is given.
File:      /usr/local/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py
Type:      method
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want like this:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Window title")
root.mainloop()
```

It's also working with tk.Toplevel()